# How to call a shared helper function from within a mutation or action in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am trying to separate out some code that is common among many calls in my Vuex mutations.  I am getting the feeling that this is discouraged but I don't understand why.

Have a look at an image of some sample code below:

I have added this 'helpers' entry in the Vuex - this obviously doesn't exist but how can I call the shared helper function 'getColumn' from mutations and/or actions?

[image]

---

Or do I have resort to calling a static method on a 'VuexHelper' class? :(

Something like:

[image]

**Note**
I have already looked at the following:

1. Vue Mixins - yes, something like that could work but is not
   supported in Vuex - *also, vue methods don't return a value*...
2. I have looked at Modules but these still don't give me what I need, i.e. a simple re-usable function that returns a value.

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I don't see why you may want to put the helper function within the store. You can just use a plain function.

```js
function getColumn(state, colName) {
  // Do your thing.
}

const vstore = new Vuex.Store({
  // ....
  mutations: {
    removeColumn(state, colName) {
      var column = getColumns(state, colName);
    }
  }
};
```

On the other hand, if you really need that, you can access the raw module and all that's included:

```
var column = this._modules.root._rawModule.helpers.getColumns(state, colName);
```

Although this syntax is not documented and can change for later versions.

Comment: Thanks for that. Even though I was hoping for a more 'in-build' support I have the feeling that I am going to have to go with this.  @Gal-Weissman's answer is more along the 'correct' lines even though it is not supported by Vuex.  So for now I'll go with this - I'll mark this as the answer unless someone comes along with a better solution.

Comment: If there is a common functionality between mutations, one way is to extract the common functionality in a new mutation and call more than one mutation from the actions. However in some situations this is not ideal, so just declaring a function at the top of the file becomes the best solution (or importing a module if the functionality is shared with other stores or components).

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your Vuex getter as a method-style getter. This lets you pass in the specific column as an argument:

```
getters: {
  getColumn: state => colName => {
    return state.columns[colName] || null
  }
}
```

Then getColumn can be used within the store like so:

```
let column = getters.getColumn('colNameString')
```

[vuex docs > getters  > method style access](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#method-style-access)

Comment: Thanks for that but Vuex doesn't technically support calling getters from mutations (they are supported through actions where the entire context is given). So even though in TypeScript I can get around with a 'var that: any = this' and then calling the getter it still doesn't feel 'right'.

Comment: True. Mutations are built specifically to alter data, not anything else. Thus you'll have the same situation with any other approach you'll pick, as you try to calculate data within a mutation. The solution is to wrap your mutation in an action and pass the calculated data to the mutation as a parameter.